# Cannot established connection using classloader

Tags: java, jdbc

[image]
        i tried to get the database connection using class loader  but it always shown null value,but when i using FileInputStream class,the connection has established,kindly guide me what mistake i have done

```
     package com.soft.dbconnection;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;

public class Connector {
    private static Connection con;
    // static FileInputStream input;
    static InputStream input = null;

    public static Connection getConnection() {
        if (con != null) {
            return con;
        } else {

            try {
                Properties p = new Properties();
                // input = new FileInputStream("F:/workspace/Programs/com.test.soft/src/db.properties");
                input = Connector.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(
                        "/com.test.soft/src/db.properties");
                p.load(input);

                String Driver = p.getProperty("driver");

                String URL = p.getProperty("url");
                String Uname = p.getProperty("uname");
                String Password = p.getProperty("password");
                Class.forName(Driver);
                con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, Uname, Password);
                return con;

            } catch (SQLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();

            } catch (ClassNotFoundException n) {
                System.out.println(n);

            } catch (IOException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
        return con;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(Connector.getConnection());

    }
}
```

Comment: Whats "/src/" doing in the path?

Comment: @MadProgrammer i have mentioned please have a look at the post,i have added the screen shot

Comment: I think you'll find "/db.properties" or "db.properties" will work...

Comment: @MadProgrammer thanks for ur guidness i have mentioned "db.properties" after that it works..

Comment: @MadProgrammer post ur answer to the Answer for this question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your confusing the paths you project is broken into and what will be available once the project is built

I think you'll find "/db.properties" or "db.properties" will work...

You should never reference "src" from your program, as "src" will not exist once it is built